# What is the default verdict for nftables rule?

Tags: linux, nftables

For example:

```bash
#!/usr/sbin/nft -f

add table ip filter_4

add chain ip filter_4 input {
    type filter hook input priority filter; policy drop;
}

add chain ip filter_4 new_in_4 {
    comment "New input IPv4 traffic"
}

# Note it's goto not jump! (thus no way out of new_in_4 chain)
add rule ip filter_4 input ct state new goto new_in_4

# Is this block drop or accept rule?
add rule ip filter_4 new_in_4 log prefix "some comment: "
```

The rule has no excplicit `accept` or `drop` verdict, so which is the default?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The rule has no excplicit `accept` or `drop` verdict, so which is the default?

None. A rule is not required to have a final verdict – if you don't specify one, then it doesn't have one. Packet processing will continue to the next rule.

If the packet reaches the end of a chain that you did `goto` to, then the result is as if it reached the end of the parent chain – in this case, the "input" chain has `policy drop`, so that will be applied.

(In other words, there *is* a way out of the new chain, just like there is a way out of the 'input' chain – the chain policy can be thought to be at the beginning of call stack and is the final place that you will "return" to. With 'jump' the stack would be `policy > chain input > chain new_in_4`, and with 'goto' it would be `policy > chain new_in_4`.)

The above is not unique to nftables; it's approximately the same in iptables (which also has both 'JUMP' and 'GOTO', chain policies, and rules without a final verdict).

---

nftables lets you see packet processing rule-by-rule – apply the rule `nftrace set 1` to your packets (preferably as early as possible) and run `nft monitor trace`.

A more readable way to write your ruleset would be:

```
#!/usr/bin/nft -f

table ip filter4 {
    chain input {
        type filter hook input priority filter; policy drop;
        ct state new goto new_in_4
    }

    chain new_in_4 {
        comment "New input IPv4 traffic"
        log prefix "some comment: "
    }
}
```

Usually the opposite of `chain new` is done – the input chain would have a single rule to blanket accept *established* packets, then everything else would be "new" and you wouldn't need the second chain at all.

```
table ip filter4 {
    chain input {
        type filter hook input priority filter; policy drop;
        ct state established,related accept

        comment "New input IPv4 traffic"
        log prefix "some comment: "
    }
}
```

Comment: Excelent explanation, it's sad I couldn't find this information on wiki or any other docs. `nftables` is great firewall otherwise, I like how it does things.